# Lightgbm binary classification model with a customized objective function returns strange prediction results

Tags: lightgbm

I am coding a binary classification model with lightgbm and need my customized objective function to solve my problem. Before I implement my own one, I tried to test with a sample customized objective function from web which is popular cross entropy function as below. However the prediction result shows very strange numbers, not like probabilities within [0,1]. Why does this happen?

I wrote the customized objective function as 'loglikelihood' and put it into the jobj=loglikelihood in the training function as the below code. The booster returns the prediction as very large numbers, not within [0,1].

```py
def loglikelihood(preds, dtrain):

    labels = dtrain.get_label()

    preds = 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-preds))
    grad = (preds - labels)
    hess = (preds * (1.0-preds))

    return grad, hess

def train():

    params ={
            'task': 'train',
            'boosting': 'gbdt',
            'objective': 'binary',
            'metric': 'auc',
            }

    clf = lgb.train(
                    params,
                    lgb_train,
                    valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_test],
                    valid_names=['train', 'test'],
                    num_boost_round=10000,
                    fobj=loglikelihood,
                    early_stopping_rounds= 200,
                    verbose_eval=100
                    )

    preds = clf.predict(valid_x, num_iteration=clf.best_iteration)
```

I expected the code return the probabilities within [0,1]

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a sigmoid function on the output of your `clf.predict`

```
def sigmoid_array(x):                                        
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

preds = sigmoid_array(clf.predict(valid_x, num_iteration=clf.best_iteration))
```

Comment: Great. You can accept the answer to show people it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have already specified the objective of lightgbm as 'binary',
the output still not represents the 'probability'.
The prediction of your model gives the raw margin scores,
thus you need to project the output into a sigmoid space yourself.

For me I prefer using this:

```html
from scipy import special
y_pred = special.expit(model.predict(X_test))
```

Additionally, there is also an existed function under the lightgbm.Booster that is called *[.predict_proba](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict_proba)*, which is different from the *.predict*, and you can check it here if you want , but it does not support customized objective functions of any kind.